# Could not enable python3 support in vim

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I tried to compile vim from source with python3 support.
So, I installed all necessary packages like python3 and python3-dev, enable python3 flags in configure, but vim dont support python3 anyway.
Here is my flaglist

```
./configure --with-features=huge             --enable-multibyte     --enable-rubyinterp=yes     --enable-python3interp=yes     --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/     --enable-perlinterp=yes     --enable-luainterp=yes             --enable-cscope    --prefix=/usr/local
```

And, when I enable python support, vim compiles with +python support, but still have -python3 flag.
What should I do?

Comment: It might be a silly question, but are you sure you're running what you actually compiled instead of the version already install on your system?

Comment: dpkg -s  vim
dpkg-query: package «vim» is not installed and no information is available

Answer (score 0):

Delete entire vim folder and recompile from sources, problem solved